# Show all the pages in a folder on one page using a web part?

Tags: web-part, pages

We are on sharepoint 2016 and we'd like to show all the page content from the pages in a specific folder on one page. Is there a way to do that? I can find web parts that show a list of pages, but not ones that show the content of those pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with the "Page Viewer" web part.

In the web part configuration select the configuration as **Web Page**, as per Microsoft, we can display the content of a web page using this option.

**Web Page**     Select this option if you want to display a Web page as the content of the Page Viewer Web Part. This option automatically enters the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (http://) in the Link text box. This is the default value.

Notes:

- Other than the "Web Page" , there will be a options **Folder** and
  **File**
- We can use the Page Viewer Web Part only in a browser that supports the HTML IFRAME element.
- Displaying a file or a folder requires Microsoft Internet Explorer.

**Supporting version:**

- SharePoint 2016,2013,2010

For more details, refer to the below MSDN article :

[Display a web page, folder, or file on a classic SharePoint page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-a-web-page-folder-or-file-on-a-classic-sharepoint-page-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527)

Comment: That only shows the content of one page or a list of the page names in that folder. I'm trying to get it to show the content of all the pages stored in the folder.